# Why doesn't a string in parentheses make a tuple with just that string?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a problem with Python threading and sending a string in the arguments.

```
def processLine(line) :
    print "hello";
    return;
```

.

```
dRecieved = connFile.readline();
processThread = threading.Thread(target=processLine, args=(dRecieved));
processThread.start();
```

Where dRecieved is the string of one line read by a connection. It calls a simple function which as of right now has only one job of printing "hello".

However I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python25\lib\threading.py", line 486, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Python25\lib\threading.py", line 446, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
TypeError: processLine() takes exactly 1 arguments (232 given)
```

232 is the length of the string that I am trying to pass, so I guess its breaking it up into each character and trying to pass the arguments like that. It works fine if I just call the function normally but I would really like to set it up as a separate thread.

Comment: Why do you have semicolons at the end of each line?

Comment: @Maikflow Isnt that a good practice? ASI converts not semicoloned lines into semicoloned in the background afaik.

Comment: @I.K. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365508/when-is-semicolon-use-in-python-considered-good-or-acceptable

Answer (score 409, accepted):

You're trying to create a tuple, but you're just parenthesizing a string :)

Add an extra ',':

```
dRecieved = connFile.readline()
processThread = threading.Thread(target=processLine, args=(dRecieved,))  # <- note extra ','
processThread.start()
```

Or use brackets to make a list:

```
dRecieved = connFile.readline()
processThread = threading.Thread(target=processLine, args=[dRecieved])  # <- 1 element list
processThread.start()
```

---

If you notice, from the stack trace: `self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)`

The `*self.__args` turns your string into a list of characters, passing them to the `processLine`
function.  If you pass it a one element list, it will pass that element as the first argument - in your case, the string.

Comment: extra parentheses in at the end of line two of the second code block.  I wanted to edit it but it is less that 6 characters

Comment: If you have arg2 with default value, do this.
`threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(arg1,),kwargs={'arg2': arg2})`

Comment: What about named args?

Answer (score 16):

I hope to provide more background knowledge here.

First, let's look at the constructor signature of the method [threading::Thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread):

```
class threading.Thread(group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={}, *, daemon=None)
```

> ***args*** is the argument ***tuple*** for the target invocation. Defaults to ().

Second, A [quirk](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) in Python about `tuple`:

> Empty tuples are constructed by an empty pair of parentheses; ***a tuple with one item*** is constructed by following a value with a ***comma*** (it is not sufficient to enclose a single value in parentheses).

On the other hand, a string is a sequence of characters, like `'abc'[1] == 'b'`. So if send a string to `args`, even in parentheses (still a sting), each character will be treated as a single parameter.

However, Python is so integrated and is not like JavaScript where extra arguments can be tolerated. Instead, it throws a `TypeError` to complain.

Answer (score 1):

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
def run(name):
    for x in range(10):
        print("helo "+name)
        sleep(1)
def run1():
    for x in range(10):
        print("hi")
        sleep(1)
T=Thread(target=run,args=("Ayla",))
T1=Thread(target=run1)
T.start()
sleep(0.2)
T1.start()
T.join()
T1.join()
print("Bye")
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations to questions and not posting purely code answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).