# Why do I get TypeError in Threading in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I've got the following code which is based off an example i found here on SO, but when i run it i get an error. Please help, i'm sure its very simple:

```
def listener(port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind(('',port))
    sock.settimeout(1) # n second(s) timeout
    try:
        while True:
            data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
            print data
    except socket.timeout:
        print 'Finished'

def startListenerThread(port):
    threading.Thread(target=listener, args=(port)).start()
```

The error i get is:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 522, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 477, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
TypeError: listener() argument after * must be a sequence, not int
```

Comment: The title of this question should be a real question like "why do I get "argument after * must be a sequence) when creating a ThreadQ?" . Proper question names help people to find the right question/answers

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The error is coming from the following line:

```
threading.Thread(target=listener, args=(port)).start()
```

The `args` parameter needs to be a sequence, I think your intention is to use a tuple, but wrapping a single value in parentheses does not accomplish this.  Here is what you need to change it to:

```
threading.Thread(target=listener, args=(port,)).start()
```

Here is a simple example showing the difference:

```
>>> (100)  # this is just value 100
100
>>> (100,) # this is a tuple containing the value 100
(100,)
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers: 3 in one minute, that's overwhelming!

Answer (score 8):

In the last line, `args=(port)` is equivalent to `args=port`. You need to put `port` into a proper tuple like this: `args=(port,)`.

Answer (score 6):

The `args` parameter to `threading.Thread` needs to be a tuple

```
threading.Thread(target=listener, args=(port)).start()
```

Note that it's not the parens that makes something a 1-element tuple, it's the comma:

```
>>> type((1))
<type 'int'>
>>> type((1,))
<type 'tuple'>
```

change the above to

```
threading.Thread(target=listener, args=(port,)).start()
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer here: [Python Threading String Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221655/python-threading-string-arguments)

Rookie mistake: (port) doesn't make a tuple, i need either args=(port,) or args=[port].