# Threading incorporated into a class

Tags: python, class, recursion, python-multithreading

I am trying to use threading in one of my features of a class. The class is not inheriting the Thread class, it is just making use of it, calling a function in the class. The code has been refined to the problem of my class.

The problem that occurs seems to be the implementation of using threads in a class and recursively calling a method? This is just my guess, I',m not a expert in python schemes so I don't know.

#### Set the thread variable in the method run to enable threading.

```
import threading

class Alpha:
    
    
        # Set variable defaults
        leader = 'Swansonburg'
        
        # - Thread variables
        MAX_CONNECTIONS = 5
        lock = threading.BoundedSemaphore(value=MAX_CONNECTIONS)
        
        
        def __init__(self, leader=''):
            
            if (leader): self.leader = leader
            

        def run(self):

            print "[+] Alpha: %s, Calling For Backup!" % self.leader

            self.ETA = 101
            for percent in range(self.ETA):

                """ SET TRUE TO ENABLE THREADING """
                THREADING = False
                
                self.lock.acquire() # Set thread cap
                
                if (not THREADING): 
                    self.CallBackup(percent)
                else:
                    t = threading.Thread(target=self.CallBackup, args=(percent))
                    t.start()
                
                
                
        
        def CallBackup(self, percent):
            if (percent == 0): pass
            elif (percent % 10 == 0) | (percent == 100):
                output = ("=" * percent) + (" %% - %d" % percent)
                print (output)
                
            self.lock.release()



def main():
    new_team = Alpha()
    
    new_team.run()
    
    

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried running this, it gave me the error that

```
CallBackup() argument after * must be a sequence, not int
```

[Why do I get TypeError in Threading in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479033/simply-python-threading-question) explains the same problem, you need to replace `args=(percent)` to `args=(percent,)` to make the argument list a sequence instead of a tuple.