# Python: Multithreading does not run

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I am trying to run some multithreaded code in python as

```
    from Queue import Queue 
    q = Queue()
    doclist=["adsas","asdasd","oipoipo"]
    for i,doc in enumerate(doclist):
        q.put(doc)
    q.join()

    threadRun.run(50, qWorker.worker(q))
```

first, i create a queue and add some stuff to it. Then, i call a method which creates and runs the threads. Here is the `threadRun.run` method

```
import threading
def run(numThreads,targetMethod):
    print "Running threads"
    for i in range(numThreads):
        t = threading.Thread(target=targetMethod)
        t.daemon=True
        t.start()
```

and here is the `qWorker.worker` method

```
def worker(qItem):
    print "Q Worker"
    while True:
            doc = qItem.get()

            try:
                print doc
                qItem.task_done()
            except:
                print "Error"
```

When i execute the above code, nothing happens. Is my approach correct? what am i missing?

Comment: Nothing happens? It doesn't print "Running threads"?

Comment: is `qWorker.worker(q)` a callable object? I think, before calling `run` python trying to calculate the value of `qWorker.worker(q)`
for passing parameters to thread use `args` parameter of `threading.Thread()`  
class threading.Thread(group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={}, *, daemon=None)

Comment: Is your code in a `__main__` block? What os are you on?

Comment: no, it does not print "Running threads"

Comment: yes, my code is in a __main__ block. i am on windows7. i have python 2.7 through anaconda

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling join on the queue before starting the threads so your code will block there.

So start the threads then run `q.join()`

**EDIT**

One more error is the passing of the queue, this:

```
 threadRun.run(50, qWorker.worker(q))
```

should be:

```
 threadRun.run(50, qWorker.worker, q)
```

So add the queue as a parameter to the run function and when you create the threads do:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=targetMethod, args=(q,))
```

The reason you saw the "Q worker" output was because you actually called the worker function here: `threadRun.run(50, qWorker.worker(q))`

Comment: That's not the full problem.

Comment: hey, that worked! i put the threadRun.run() call before the q.join()

Comment: and now the qWorker.worker() runs as expected. but i still did not see "Running threads" how do i know that the execution was actually multithreaded?

Comment: i did see "Q Worker" but i was expecting "Running threads" before that. However, nothing was printed

Comment: correct! Now it makes sense. Now it prints "Running threads". However, i get TypeError: worker() argument after * must be a sequence, not instance

Comment: ok, got it. the solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479033/why-do-i-get-typeerror-in-threading-in-python

Comment: does this make sense?

Comment: Sorry, you need a comma at the t = "threading.Thread(target=targetMethod, args=(q,))" I changed my answer