# how to pass argument into threading?

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to add 5 for every element in range(1,100)  with threading module,
to watch which rusult is in which thread.
I finished almost of the code,but how to pass argument into  threading.Thread?

```
import threading,queue
x=range(1,100)
y=queue.Queue()
for i in x:
    y.put(i)

def myadd(x):
    print(x+5)


for i in range(5):
    print(threading.Thread.getName())
    threading.Thread(target=myadd,args=x).start() #it is wrong here
    y.join()
```

Thinks to  dano ,it is ok now ,in order to run in interactive way, i rewrite it as:

method 1:run in interactive way.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import threading
x = range(1, 100)

def myadd(x):
    print("Current thread: {}. Result: {}.".format(threading.current_thread(), x+5))

def run():
    t = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
    t.map(myadd, x)
    t.shutdown()
run()
```

methdo 2:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import threading
x = range(1, 100)
def myadd(x):
    print("Current thread: {}. Result: {}.".format(threading.current_thread(), x+5))
def run():
    t = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
    t.map(myadd, x)
    t.shutdown()
if __name__=="__main__":
    run()
```

What about if more args to be passed into  ThreadPoolExecutor?
I want to calculate 1+3, 2+4, 3+45  until  100+102 with multi-processing module. 
And what about 20+1,20+2,20+3 until 20+100 with multi-processing module?

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
do = ThreadPool(5)
def myadd(x,y):
    print(x+y)

do.apply(myadd,range(3,102),range(1,100))
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to create a thread pool with the `for i in range(5)` thing you're doing?

Comment: You put a hundred things on a Queue and never take them off, then `.join()` to wait for it to become empty? That's not going to fly. Surely your `myadd()` function should have no argument but read an element from the Queue. Then you stand some chance of detecting it's empty. Sadly at present the `join()` call stops at the first iteration because the Queue isn't empty, and has no chance to become so. So I suspect you see one line of output then your program stalls. It would have been helpful to have such information ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to create a thread pool manually, so that five threads are used to add up all 100 results. If this is the case, I would recommend using `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` for this:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import threading
import queue

x = range(1, 100)

def myadd(x):
    print("Current thread: {}. Result: {}.".format(
               threading.current_thread(), x+5))

t = ThreadPool(5)
t.map(myadd, x)
t.close()
t.join()
```

If you're using Python 3.x, you could use [`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) instead:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import threading

x = range(1, 100)

def myadd(x):
    print("Current thread: {}. Result: {}.".format(threading.current_thread(), x+5))

t = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
t.map(myadd, x)
t.shutdown()
```

I think there are two issues with your original code. First, you need to pass a tuple to the `args` keyword argument, not a single element:

```
threading.Thread(target=myadd,args=(x,))
```

However, you're also trying to pass the entire list (or `range` object, if using Python 3.x) returned by `range(1,100)` to `myadd`, which isn't really what you want to do. It's also not clear what you're using the queue for. Maybe you meant to pass that to `myadd`?

One final note: Python uses a Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), which prevents more than one thread from using the CPU at a time. This means that doing CPU-bound operations (like addition) in threads provides no performance boost in Python, since only one of the threads will ever run at a time. Therefore, In Python it's preferred to use the multiple processes to parallelize CPU-bound operations. You could make the above code use multiple processes by replacing the `ThreadPool` in the first example with `from mulitprocessing import Pool`. In the second example, you would use `ProcessPoolExecutor` instead of `ThreadPoolExecutor`. You would also probably want to replace `threading.current_thread()` with `os.getpid()`.

**Edit:**

Here's how to handle the case where there are two different args to pass:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def myadd(x,y):
    print(x+y)

def do_myadd(x_and_y):
    return myadd(*x_and_y)

do = ThreadPool(5)    
do.map(do_myadd, zip(range(3, 102), range(1, 100)))
```

We use `zip` to create a list where we pair together each variable in the range:

```
[(3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 3), ...]
```

We use `map` to call `do_myadd` with each tuple in that list, and `do_myadd` uses tuple expansion (`*x_and_y`), to expand the tuple into two separate arguments, which get passed to `myadd`.

Comment: some thing wrong in example 2,there is no join() ,when i run it ,can't exit from it,some thraeds can not be killed,how to fix it?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature I've added in the calls to properly close/shutdown both pool objects. However, leaving those out shouldn't have prevented the threads from being killed, as far as I know. Does it work with the `shutdown` call added in?

Comment: would you mind to help me solve the problem  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075356/how-to-write-the-map-sentence-here-to-call-array-to-calculate-with-threadpool-mo   ?

Comment: it is t.map(myadd, x)  t.join()  t.close() ,not t.map(myadd, x)   t.close()  t.join() .

Comment: @it_is_a_literature, no [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.join) state you must call `close` before `join`.

Comment: think for telling me,a new problem to see the my edited post at the top,apply function can't run.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature I edited my answer to show you how to do what you're trying. But in the future, you should ask a new question when you have new requirements, rather than change the question and unaccept the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here you need to pass a tuple rather than using a single element.

For making a tuple the code would be .

```
dRecieved = connFile.readline();
processThread = threading.Thread(target=processLine, args=(dRecieved,)); 
processThread.start();
```

Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221655/python-threading-string-arguments) for the more explanation

Answer (score 0):

From:

```
import threading,queue
x=range(1,100)
y=queue.Queue()
for i in x:
    y.put(i)

def myadd(x):
    print(x+5)


for i in range(5):
    print(threading.Thread.getName())
    threading.Thread(target=myadd,args=x).start() #it is wrong here
    y.join()
```

To:

```
import threading
import queue

# So print() in various threads doesn't garble text; 
# I hear it is better to use RLock() instead of Lock().
screen_lock = threading.RLock() 

# I think range() is an iterator or generator. Thread safe?
argument1 = range(1, 100)
argument2 = [100,] * 100 # will add 100 to each item in argument1

# I believe this creates a tuple (immutable). 
# If it were a mutable object then perhaps it wouldn't be thread safe.
data = zip(argument1, argument2)

# object where multiple threads can grab data while avoiding deadlocks.
q = queue.Queue()

# Fill the thread-safe queue with mock data
for item in data:
    q.put(item)

# It could be wiser to use one queue for each inbound data stream.
# For example one queue for file reads, one queue for console input,
# one queue for each network socket. Remembering that rates of 
# reading files and console input and receiving network traffic all
# differ and you don't want one I/O operation to block another.
# inbound_file_data = queue.Queue()
# inbound_console_data = queue.Queue() # etc.

# This function is a thread target
def myadd(thread_name, a_queue):

    # This thread-targetted function blocks only within each thread;
    # at a_queue.get() and at a_queue.put() (if queue is full).
    #
    # Each thread targetting this function has its own copy of
    # this functions local() namespace. So each thread will 
    # pause when the queue is empty, on queue.get(), or when 
    # the queue is full, on queue.put(). With one queue, this 
    # means all threads will block at the same time, when the 
    # single queue is full or when the single queue is empty 
    # unless we check for the number of remaining items in the
    # queue before we do a queue.get() and if none remain in the 
    # queue just exit this function. This presumes the data is 
    # not a continues and slow stream like a network connection 
    # or a rotating log file but limited like a closed file.

    # Let each thread continue to read from the global 
    # queue until it is empty. 
    # 
    # This is a bad use-case for using threading. 
    # 
    # If each thread had a separate queue it would be 
    # a better use-case. You don't want one slow stream of 
    # data blocking the processing of a fast stream of data.
    #
    # For a single stream of data it is likely better just not 
    # to use threads. However here is a single "global" queue 
    # example...

    # presumes a_queue starts off not empty
    while a_queue.qsize():
        arg1, arg2 = a_queue.get() # blocking call

        # prevent console/tty text garble
        if screen_lock.acquire():
            print('{}: {}'.format(thread_name, arg1 + arg2))
            print('{}: {}'.format(thread_name, arg1 + 5))
            print()
            screen_lock.release()
        else:
            # print anyway if lock fails to acquire
            print('{}: {}'.format(thread_name, arg1 + arg2))
            print('{}: {}'.format(thread_name, arg1 + 5))
            print()

        # allows .join() to keep track of when queue finished
        a_queue.task_done()


# create threads and pass in thread name and queue to thread-target function
threads = []
for i in range(5):
    thread_name = 'Thread-{}'.format(i)
    thread = threading.Thread(
        name=thread_name, 
        target=myadd, 
        args=(thread_name, q))

    # Recommended:
    # queues = [queue.Queue() for index in range(len(threads))] # put at top of file 
    # thread = threading.Thread(
    #   target=myadd, 
    #   name=thread_name, 
    #   args=(thread_name, queues[i],))
    threads.append(thread)

# some applications should start threads after all threads are created.
for thread in threads:
   thread.start()

# Each thread will pull items off the queue. Because the while loop in 
# myadd() ends with the queue.qsize() == 0 each thread will terminate 
# when there is nothing left in the queue.
```