# Start a flask application in separate thread

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I'm currently developing a Python application on which I want to see real-time statistics. I wanted to use `Flask` in order to make it easy to use and to understand.

The issue is that my Flask server should start at the very beginning of my Python application and stop at the very end. It should look like this:

```
def main():
    """ My main application """
    from watcher.flask import app
    # watcher.flask define an app as in the Quickstart flask documentation.
    # See: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#quickstart

    app.run() # Starting the flask application

    do_my_stuff()

    app.stop() # Undefined, for the idea
```

Because I need my application context (for the statistics), I can't use a `multiprocessing.Process`. Then I was trying to use a `threading.Thread`, but it looks like Werkzeug doesn't like it:

```
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:10079/
Exception in thread Flask Server:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File ".../develop-eggs/watcher.flask/src/watcher/flask/__init__.py", line 14, in _run
    app.run(host=HOSTNAME, port=PORT, debug=DEBUG)
  File ".../eggs/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 772, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File ".../eggs/Werkzeug-0.7-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/serving.py", line 609, in run_simple
    run_with_reloader(inner, extra_files, reloader_interval)
  File ".../eggs/Werkzeug-0.7-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/serving.py", line 524, in run_with_reloader
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, lambda *args: sys.exit(0))
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
```

How can I do that without running Flask in the main thread?

Comment: I've ran Flask apps in a separate thread, so this error you're seeing is surprising. Do you have the full traceback?

Comment: Full traceback added

Comment: Did you somehow set `app.debug = True`?

Comment: Yes I did. It can't be set to True if i'm threading ?

Comment: Can you show the code where you ran flask in a separate thread?

Comment: Generally, it is not a good idea to run server on separate "thread", what you need to do is to run server on separate "process". Because OS usually schedules the threads in round-robin fashion. Meaning that, main thread and child thread of process are usually swapped in and swapped out, meaning that, when your thread on which server is running is swapped out then server will not be able to process any request as it is down. On the other hand, if your server is running on a "process" using multi-processing then server will always be online because processes are not swapped in and out.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You're running `Flask` in debug mode, which enables **the reloader** (reloads the Flask server when your code changes).

Flask can run just fine in a separate thread, but the reloader expects to run in the main thread.

---

To solve your issue, you should either disable debug (`app.debug = False`), or disable the reloader (`app.use_reloader=False`).

Those can also be passed as arguments to `app.run`: `app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you add a little code sample / documentation link about how to close the server properly in a separate thread ?

Comment: @FunkySayu Typically you'll create a `/shutdown` route. The route code does: `flask.request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')()`. To shutdown the server you simply make a HTTP request to `/shutdown`. For security you'll usually add a token that only your app knows so that no one else can shut down the server (and you call `/shutdown?token=somethingSecret`)

Comment: Okay that's what explained the answer below. Now I got it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: but it's useful reload server when code changes, can I use both of them

Comment: Then how do you stop ?

Comment: this just disables the nice error view in the browser, but on flask console i still get the `ValueError: signal only works in main thread`

Answer (score 55):

Updated answer for Python 3 that's a bit simpler:

```
from flask import Flask                                                         
import threading

data = 'foo'
host_name = "0.0.0.0"
port = 23336
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    threading.Thread(target=lambda: app.run(host=host_name, port=port, debug=True, use_reloader=False)).start()
```

Comment: Might want to fix the import statement to `import threading`. Cannot make the edit as edits are required to change > 6 character.

Comment: What if I need to pass an option in app.run? Like app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
I tried to do this but then the threading failed

Comment: @AmanKejriwal use a seperate function and do app.run with the parameters you want and call that function inside your thread.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: @AmanKejriwal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221655/python-threading-string-arguments/58043526

Comment: this does not work with a production server implementation right? with gunicorn or uwsgi?

Comment: @AmanKejriwal `threading.Thread(target=lambda: app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=23336, debug=True, use_reloader=False)).start()`

Comment: Updated to include @imath's suggestion

Answer (score 21):

If you are looking for accessing iPython terminal in Flask
run your application in a separate thread. Try this example:

```
from flask import Flask                                                         
import thread

data = 'foo'
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return data

def flaskThread():
    app.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread.start_new_thread(flaskThread, ())
```

(Run this file in iPython)

Comment: This is just perfect answer!

Answer (score 2):

From the [werkzeug documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/serving/#shutting-down-the-server):

> Shutting Down The Server
>
> New in version 0.7.
>
> Starting with Werkzeug 0.7 the development server provides a way to
>   shut down the server after a request. This currently only works with
>   Python 2.6 and later and will only work with the development server.
>   To initiate the shutdown you have to call a function named
>   'werkzeug.server.shutdown' in the WSGI environment:
>
> ```
> def shutdown_server(environ):
>     if not 'werkzeug.server.shutdown' in environ:
>         raise RuntimeError('Not running the development server')
>     environ['werkzeug.server.shutdown']()
> ```

Comment: I don't get your answer. In what I understood, this is a way to stop the server, but my issue is not only how to stop the server but also how to start it. Could you add a little example please ?

Answer (score 1):

The original question was about how to run in a thread, and other answers address this, simply make sure to `use_reloader=False`.  However graceful server shutdown when running in a thread I've still not found an answer to.  One answer seems outdated as link to the current version of [werkzeug shutting down the server](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/serving/#shutting-down-the-server) suggests using a `multiprocess.Process` and calling `terminate` on that process.

I'm interested if anyone has a solution to graceful server shutdown when the flask app is running in a thread instead of a subprocess.

Comment: To answer my own question https://stackoverflow.com/a/45017691/7619746 seems to work perfectly.