# TypeError: no default __reduce__ due to non-trivial __cinit__

Tags: python, kivy, pickle

I was trying to make a simple flask and kivy app, but when i run the app it gives me an typeerror. I am facing an issue, i took this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49884548/how-to-run-kivy-and-flask-apps-together)

Here's my code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


# common modules
import sys
import os
import time
import signal
from multiprocessing import Process

# Flask modules
from flask import Flask

# wsgi (Web Server Gateway Interface) modules
import eventlet
from eventlet import wsgi

# async server setup
app = Flask(__name__)

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print (" CTRL + C detected, exiting ... ")
    exit(0)


# kivy gui classes ######################################################     
class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name="MAIN SCREEN"
        super(Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class MainApp(App):
    MainScreenTitle = "MainScreen title"
    MainScreenLabel = "MainScreen label"
    MessageButtonEnter = "START"
    MessageButtonExit = "EXIT"

    def start_Flask(self):
        print("Starting Flask...")
        wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 5000)), app)     # deploy as an eventlet WSGI server


    def start(self):
        print ("starting Flask as process...")
        global p1
        p1 = Process(target=self.start_Flask) # assign Flask to a process
        p1.daemon = True
        p1.start()  #launch Flask as separate process
    
    def stop(self):
        print ("terminating Flask and exiting...")
        global p1
        p1.terminate()
        exit(1)

    def build(self):
        sm = Builder.load_string("""

ScreenManager
    MainScreen:
        size_hint: 1, .7
        auto_dismiss: False
        title: app.MainScreenTitle       
        title_align: "center"

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            Label:
                text: app.MainScreenLabel
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "horizontal"
                spacing: 10
                size_hint: 1, .5
                Button:
                    text: app.MessageButtonEnter  # start app
                    on_press:
                        app.start()
                Button:
                    text: app.MessageButtonExit  # exit app
                    on_press:
                        app.stop()

        """)

        return sm


# main ################################################
if __name__ == '__main__':

    #CTRL+C signal handler
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)

    MainApp().run()   # run Kivy app
```

But it is giving me an error:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Welcome\.kivy\logs\kivy_21-07-22_40.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\pythonw.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Activate GLES2/ANGLE context
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <angle_sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 2.0.0 (ANGLE 2.1.13739 git hash: 385fb40fd460)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Google Inc.'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'ANGLE (Mobile Intel(R) 965 Express Chipset Family Direct3D11 vs_4_0 ps_4_0)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00 (ANGLE 2.1.13739 git hash: 385fb40fd460)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
starting Flask as process...
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\my projects of python\Safar\new 1.py", line 100, in <module>
     MainApp().run()   # run Kivy app
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 950, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 582, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 347, in mainloop
     self.idle()
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 391, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 342, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 248, in post_dispatch_input
     listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1412, in on_motion
     self.dispatch('on_touch_down', me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1428, in on_touch_down
     if w.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 1198, in on_touch_down
     return super(ScreenManager, self).on_touch_down(touch)
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\relativelayout.py", line 297, in on_touch_down
     ret = super(RelativeLayout, self).on_touch_down(touch)
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down
     self.dispatch('on_press')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 705, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1248, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1132, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 57, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "<string>", line 21, in <module>
   File "D:\my projects of python\Safar\new 1.py", line 53, in start
     p1.start()  #launch Flask as separate process
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
     self._popen = self._Popen(self)
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
     return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 326, in _Popen
     return Popen(process_obj)
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
     reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
     ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
   File "stringsource", line 2, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__reduce_cython__
 TypeError: no default __reduce__ due to non-trivial __cinit__
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.