# Use Dash (plot.ly) in PyQt5 GUI

Tags: python, pyqt5, plotly

I am running into a problem while trying to create a dashboard with Dash (plotly), while using a GUI created with PyQt5.

I have tried to have the following example code both as a module and at the end of my code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html


def run_dash(data, layout):


   app = dash.Dash()

   app.layout = html.Div(children=[
   html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

   html.Div(children='''
    Dash: A web application framework for Python.
   '''),

   dcc.Graph(
    id='example-graph',
    figure={
        'data': data,
        'layout': layout
    }
)
])
   app.run_server(debug=True)
```

But everytime I get the error `can't find '__main__' module in ''`

I know that initially, to create a Dash a main guard like the following is used:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run_server(debug=True)
```

But I already have a main guard for my MainWindow so I can't figure out how to make both work together. For reference, this is my MainWindow main guard:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWin = MainWindow()
mainWin.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I have updated my question as I have advanced on it and have provided a code that might be more helpful. Please don't hesitate to inform me if it is still not correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to execute Dash in another thread, when executing it in another thread you could have problems, but using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31265602/6622587) you get the following:

```
import sys

import threading

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html


def run_dash(data, layout):
    app = dash.Dash()

    app.layout = html.Div(children=[
        html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

        html.Div(children='''
            Dash: A web application framework for Python.
        '''),

        dcc.Graph(
            id='example-graph',
            figure={
                'data': data,
                'layout': layout
            })
        ])
    app.run_server(debug=False)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = [
        {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
        {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
    ]

    layout = {
        'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
    }

    threading.Thread(target=run_dash, args=(data, layout), daemon=True).start()
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```