# Flask (running a REST server) conflicts with OpenCV reading a webcam on Ubuntu

Tags: python, opencv, flask

I'm making a large program that has to use a webcam via `OpenCV` and also has to act as a `REST` server.  The functionality of the two is not related, i.e. I'm not asking how to send a message via `REST`, that is a different topic entirely.

The concern I'm having is if I start up a Flask app acting as a REST server, then the webcam can't connect.  Here is small example that demonstrates the concern:

```
# test.py

import numpy as np
import cv2
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

flaskApp = Flask(__name__)

def main():

    flaskApp.run(debug=True)

    while True:
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

        keyPress = cv2.waitKey(10)
        if keyPress == ord('q'):
            break
        # end if

    # end while

    # When everything done, release the capture
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
# end function

@flaskApp.route('/post_number', methods=['POST'])
def post_number():
    if not request.json or not 'data' in request.json:
        print('error')
    # end if

    if request.json is None:
        print('error, request.json is None')
    # end if

    if not 'data' in request.json:
        print('error, \'data\' is not in request.json')
    # end if

    data = request.json['data']
    print('data = ' + str(data))

    return jsonify({'data': data}), 201
# end function

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I comment out the `flaskApp.run(debug=True)` line then the webcam connects and shows streaming frames in the OpenCV window as expected.  However with the `flaskApp.run(debug=True)` included as above, the OpenCV window never appears and I get this output:

```
$ python3 test.py 
 * Serving Flask app "cam_test" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
[ WARN:0] global /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (887) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 297-109-197
```

So the `Flask` app starts successfully (I can even successfully send POST messages via a test client) but the OpenCV windows never appears, and please note the `[ WARN:0] global /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (887) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index` line in the above output.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 if that matters.  Video for linux (4VL) is the standard way (perhaps the only way?) to read from webcams on Ubuntu.

It seems there is a conflict between `Flask` and `OpenCV` / `V4L` for some resource, however I'm not sure what that resource is.  Is there a way to configure Flask so it does not use the same resources as an OpenCV webcam, or some other way to resolve this so this example app can receive a webcam feed and act as a REST server at the same time?

--- Edit ---

@dtc just pointed out an oversight I made in the comments, that being that execution never gets past the `flaskApp.run(debug=True)` line, so even if the webcam connected the OpenCV window would never show.  This begs the question as to how the small example should be set up.  I can't start `flaskApp` as a separate multi-process because I need the the REST message received and the info for the image to both be accessed, and spawning a multiprocess would make the memory separate.

Comment: quick question: isn't the program just going to hang on `flaskApp.run(debug=True)`? what happens if you print afterwards?

Comment: Good call, it never gets past that line.  I editing my question per your comment.

Comment: Can you explain more why you think they cannot be run as separate processes? What is the "info for the image" that needs to be shared? And why can this not happen through an intermediary like a database or file system?

Comment: what @noslenkwah said. actually, the question might be "what are you trying to achieve on the high level"? (e.g: i want some user to make web requests that trigger the camera to behave a certain way)

Comment: To make a long story short, I need to acquire images and also other data from separate multiprocessed.  All the data need to be in the same memory space to be processed before a decision can be make (you've probably heard the term "sensor fusion" before).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @dtc the main problem was I was overlooking execution stopping on the `flaskApp.run()` line.  From this post

[Start a flask application in separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264826/start-a-flask-application-in-separate-thread/31265602#31265602)

the easy solution is to use a separate thread.

Complete working example:

server:

```
# server_and_cam.py

import numpy as np
import cv2
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import threading

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

flaskApp = Flask(__name__)

def main():

    threading.Thread(target=flaskApp.run).start()

    while True:
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

        keyPress = cv2.waitKey(10)
        if keyPress == ord('q'):
            break
        # end if

    # end while

    # When everything done, release the capture
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
# end function

@flaskApp.route('/post_number', methods=['POST'])
def post_number():
    if request.json is None:
        print('error, request.json is None')
    # end if

    if not 'number' in request.json:
        print('error, \'number\' is not in request.json')
    # end if

    numReceived = request.json['number']
    print('numReceived = ' + str(numReceived))

    return jsonify({'number': numReceived}), 201
# end function

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

client:

```
# client.py

import requests
import json
import time

numToSend = 0

while True:
    time.sleep(1)

    # set the url
    url = 'http://localhost:5000/post_number'

    # configure headers
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}

    # build the data and put into json format
    data = {'number': str(numToSend)}
    data_json = json.dumps(data)

    # send message to server via POST
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data_json)
    # print response code
    print('response = ' + str(response))

    numToSend += 1
# end while
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) instead of [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)

Comment: I can't, in the big app I mentioned above I need the image and the REST message in the same memory, and spawning a multiprocess puts them in different memory.  I realize Python doesn't have true multithreading due to the GIL but if the results have to be accessed in the same memory space there isn't much choice with Python.

Comment: You can use [Queues or Pipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) to communicate between processes ;)

Comment: That's the whole point of using REST, there is another multiprocess, but all the data has to end up in the same memory space (images + other data) for the processing to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with how `Werkzeug` (the debugger used by `Flask`) reloads the application when changes are made to the code.

When you first run your app, `python` executes all the code until it hits `app.run(...)`. If the debug mode is enabled (`debug=True`), which implicitly enables the **reloader** (`use_reloader=True`) by default, it will restart your app in a new child process in order to be able to kill and restart it whenever needed. Having that said, your code is actually beeing executed twice. The first time by the parent process, where the debugger lives in and than again by the child process. The parent process however, is the first one that executes `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` and thus blocks the device file `/dev/video0` since it never releases it again, until it terminates.

The solution here is to make sure, that you do not open the device file in the parent process where the reloader runs. This can achieved by many ways.

The most convenient way is to check the environment variable `WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN`, which is set by `Werkzeug` when it starts the reloader. This way you can still use the debug mode and its reloading functionality while making sure that `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` isn't called by the same process `Werkzeug` lives in and thus does not block `/dev/video0`:

```
if os.environ.get('WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN') or Flask.debug is False:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

**Note:** The condition `or Flask.debug is False` is to make sure that your code will still run when you disable the debug mode and thus the reloader. However, `WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN` [**is only set if the reloader itself is enabled!**](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/cbd049d88727936173386d2e80bb5ffa51fedd6e/werkzeug/_reloader.py#L129) With that said, you could actually run the app in debug mode with the reloader beeing disabled: app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, use_reloader=False). In this case the code will never get executed since both conditions will evaluate to `False`. So keep this in mind.