# Combining Plotly-Dash with a Tkinter GUI - Dash forces to execute the Tk-mainloop again

Tags: python, tkinter, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm currently developing a small tool thats parsing some input files given by the user in a Tkinter GUI. It then starts a Dash-Server to visualize the parsed data.

The problem that I'm facing right now is that the call of `dash_app.run_server()` seems to reexecute the `mainloop` of the GUI so that a new window is opened and the Dash-Server crashes. But that only happens once. If I start the process again from the new window, the server properly starts and no new window appears.

I also tried to start Dash inside a new thread but it seems like it needs to run in the main-thread so that is no option.

Are there any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Minimal Example:

```
from tkinter import *
import dash
import dash_html_components as html


class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        Button(self, text="Start",
               command=self.start).pack()

    def start(self):
        self.destroy()
        plotter = Plotter()


class Plotter():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__run_dash()

    def __run_dash(self):
        dash_app = dash.Dash(__name__, prevent_initial_callbacks=True)
        dash_app.layout = html.H1("Test")
        dash_app.run_server(debug=True)


def main():
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Note that you *can* do `dash_app.run_server()` in a thread other than main, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31265602/14747239) for details.

Comment: Well, sometimes it's that easy. Thank you.