# Python threading error - must be an iterable, not int

Tags: python, multithreading, regression, python-multithreading, iterable

I'm trying to calculate rolling r-squared of regression among first column and other columns in a dataframe (first column and second, first column and third etc.) But when I try threading, it kept telling me the error that

> TypeError: ParallelRegression() argument after * must be an iterable, not int".

I'm wondering how do I fix this? Thanks very much!

```
import threading

totalThreads=3 #three different colors
def ParallelRegression(threadnum):
    for i in range(threadnum):
        res[:,i]=sm.OLS(df.iloc[:,0], df.iloc[:,i+1]).fit().rsquared
threads=[]
for threadnum in range(totalThreads):
    t=threading.Thread(target=ParallelRegression,args=(threadnum))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
for threadnum in range(totalThreads):
    threads[threadnum].join()
```

See a summary of the data (df) in the picture linked below:

[image]

Comment: `args=(threadnum)` looks like it might be a typo. Is args supposed to be a tuple? One-element tuples need a trailing comma: `args=(threadnum,)`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`threading.Thread` class needs an iterable of arguments as the `args` parameter. You're passing `args=(threadnum)` which is a single `int` object, you need to pass some iterable object that would allow multiple args, even when you only want to pass one arg.

`args=[threadnum]` would work, because that makes a `list` which is iterable.

Comment: Why answer something that could be considered a typo, _and_ has been asked and answered countless times already? [This duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221655/python-threading-string-arguments) was literally my first google result and took a whopping 5 seconds to find.

Comment: Changing `args` to a list works on my machine, and I'd expect it to work on most Python distributions/environments, but I think it's an implementation detail that shouldn't be depended on. The docs for [`Thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) only say that args is "the argument tuple for the target invocation". If you give it anything other than a tuple, let the buyer beware.

Comment: @Aran-Fey why not? Is it frowned upon to answer questiosn?

Comment: It is frowned upon to answer obvious duplicates, yes. If you need to know why: Because it's better if we have all the answers in a single place.

Comment: Please see [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)

Answer (score 11):

There is another solution: add a comma at the end of "threadnum"

```
t=threading.Thread(target=ParallelRegression,args=(threadnum,))
```