# Passing string into Python's threading.Thread as an arg

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to figure out how to pass a string as an argument in Python `threading.Thread`.  This problem has been encountered before: [Python Threading String Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221655/python-threading-string-arguments)

**Is there a better way to pass in a string?**  There has to be a more obvious way, and I am just too new to coding to figure it out.

**Code Block A**

```
import threading

def start_my_thread():
    my_thread = threading.Thread(target=my_func, args="string")
    my_thread.start()

def my_func(input):
    print(input)
```

Result:
`TypeError: my_func() takes 1 positional argument but 6 were given`

**Code Block B**

```
import threading

def start_my_thread():
    my_thread = threading.Thread(target=my_func, args=("string",))
    my_thread.start()

def my_func(input):
    print(input)
```

Result: `string`

Answer (score 0):

you can inherit Thread,and define my_func as run method.and create a new instance.

```
import threading


class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,string):
        super().__init__()
        self.string = string
    def run(self):
        print(self.string)
# def start_my_thread():
#     my_thread = threading.Thread(target=my_func, args=("string",))
#     my_thread.start()

# def my_func(input):
#     print(input)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyThread("hello").start()
```